# Centering a Box Layout after removing components

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a program which creates JButtons which are then added to a JPanel with a BoxLayout which is set to place them vertically. Occasionally the first button is intentionally removed from the JPanel. Initially the Buttons are centered correctly and the Buttons are removing successfully as well. The problem is that the remaining buttons then move apart to fill the space. This is not what I would like, instead, I would like them to re-center along the y-axis without moving apart.

I have a Class which extends JPanel. In the constructor the BoxLayout is created.

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 500));
setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

Creating the buttons is currently a method in this class:

```
createButtons(int numButtons){
for (int i=0;i<numButtons;i++) {
    add(new JButton());
}
```

And removal is another method:

```
removeButton(){
    if(getComponentCount()>1){
        remove(0);
        validate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how the make the Buttons remain centered along the y-axis without spreading apart to fill the containing panel?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - why does that code have an **attribute** called `getComponentCount`?  I would have expected `componentCount` or `getComponentCount()`.

Comment: it is supposed to be getComponentCount(), that was a typo when writing the question! My bad, will change it now. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: *"will change it now"*  No, don't edit it by hand.  **Always copy/paste code, HTML/XML or input/output.**  And while you are at it, post an **SSCCE rather than code snippets.**  After looking at a few other questions, I was just trying to turn those snippets into compilable code when I noted the odd 'attribute' name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of glue in BoxLayouts which uses a invisble component as a filler(glue), which I think should help to keep the buttons centered, see these 2 links: [BoxLayout docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) and [BoxLayout - Filler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) this site too has some great tutorial on Boxlayout with glue: [BoxLayout Glue](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/BoxLayoutGlueSample.htm) and [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/UsingGlue.htm)

Comment: I have heard of this but wasn't too sure how it worked. I just tried adding glue before and after the for loop which creates the buttons and all the buttons disappeared. Not too sure why that happened. Do you know if glue counts as a component? So if I add glue first, then do remove(0), will it remove the glue?

Comment: @Invincibloobles yes as far as i know it is, its an invisble, component

Comment: Okay, so I've added glue before and after the create button loop and the buttons now appear. I have changed remove so it now does `remove(1)` instead of 0, so that it does not remove the glue. But it still doesn't appear to be working. The buttons still move apart

Comment: @Invincibloobles for help sooner please post an http://sscce.org, which is a small exmaple that can be compiled from a simple copy and paste and illistrates your probelm this will help me to test your code and give you appropriate help!

Comment: Lost internet connection for a while so only just seen some of these responses but in the end I got it working with glue to center the buttons and then a few struts to space them out a small amount (4 or 5 pixels or so)

Comment: @Invincibloobles atleast its working :). Thats what counts (and of course that you learnt something new)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem. Maybe I missed a step but in the following snippet, all components are horizontally centered and aligned at the top. Whenever a component is removed, the buttons below are automatically stacked at the top. Maybe start from this snippet to show us what your problem is:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestButtons {

    protected void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test buttons/BoxLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        // panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 500));
        BoxLayout mgr = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(mgr);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            final JButton button = new JButton("Remove Hello World " + (i + 1));
            button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    panel.remove(button);
                    panel.revalidate();
                    panel.repaint();
                }
            });
            panel.add(button);
        }
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestButtons().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is an issue with using BOX Layout.  The buttons do remain centered but "Fill" to the edges of the pane they are added to.  I believe the correct way to do this (if you know the number of buttons you were going to create) is to use a grid Layout with the setPreferedSize method.

```
JButton btn = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
panel.add(btn);
```

Comment: Yes, I believe you may be right. Problem is it also seems to completely disregard the setPreferedSize() command and still works the same way. Is there an alternative layout that could be used instead?

Comment: Grid layout would work, but you have to know the columns and rows when you create the panel.  you can always add on extra rows, but the column count has to be right.  It just won't fill the extra rows if you don't use them all.  Also, the post below mine has suggested glue in BoxLayouts, which I am not fermiliar with but you may want to concider it.

Comment: Don't force the preferred size of components (unless you are also performing the painting/rendering of it). Jbutton are L&F dependent, hence 40x40 may be too big in some case and too small in some others.

Comment: BoxLayout only party honors the setPreferredSize() method (layout managers are free to honor or ignore setMaximumSize(), setMinimumSize(), and setPreferredSize() methods). BoxLayout honors max and min size but for preferredSize it depends on the direction of the layout: X_AXIS–honors preferred width and Y_AXIS–honors preferred height